# Python function takes a long time to return after final statement

Tags: python-3.x, excel, docx, win32com

I have a Python program I'm using to parse through a bunch of data. For some reason, it takes a long time for the callee to return control to the caller after its final statement.

parser.py

```py
def gen_report(self):
    xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    doc = docx.Document()

    # Data shuffling here. Most of the parsing has been completed previously, so this function
    # primarily just copies charts from Excel into a Word document and then adds headings
    # and such to the Word doc.

    doc.save(doc_name)
    xl.Quit()
    print('Report generated successfully!')
```

gui.py

```py
def parse_thread(self):
    parser.gen_report()
    print('Report generation returned')
```

The final statement in `gen_report()` is the print statement, and I would think that the print statement in `parse_thread()` would be executed almost immediately afterward. But instead it takes sometimes up to 15 seconds after the first print statement before the second print statement is executed.

I thought this might be something to do with parsing through a lot of data and garbage collection, but disabling garbage collection did not change the performance at all. I was also able to run the program with CProfile and see that `parse_thread` is taking up most of the execution time, the majority of which I would assume is when the program is hanging after returning from report generation. Garbage collection doesn't even show up in the 20 items that take the most time:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   20.374   20.374   32.621   32.621 gui.py:97(parse_thread)
       41    3.564    0.087    3.564    0.087 {method 'InvokeTypes' of 'PyIDispatch' objects}
        2    2.316    1.158    2.316    1.158 {built-in method pythoncom.CoCreateInstance}
        7    0.655    0.094    0.655    0.094 {built-in method PIL._imaging.grabclipboard_win32}
        1    0.649    0.649    8.662    8.662 Parser.py:386(gen_report)
        9    0.504    0.056    0.504    0.056 {method 'encode' of 'ImagingEncoder' objects}
   834432    0.353    0.000    0.356    0.000 worksheet.py:247(_get_cell)
    73864    0.317    0.000    0.530    0.000 _writer.py:70(lxml_write_cell)
  1956380    0.228    0.000    0.228    0.000 worksheet.py:347(<genexpr>)
   683154    0.221    0.000    0.531    0.000 worksheet.py:216(cell)
   606673    0.202    0.000    0.682    0.000 worksheet.py:515(<genexpr>)
       62    0.199    0.003    0.428    0.007 worksheet.py:339(max_row)
      224    0.175    0.001    0.175    0.001 {method 'Bind' of 'PyITypeComp' objects}
        9    0.156    0.017    0.156    0.017 {method 'close' of '_io.BufferedRandom' objects}
    73800    0.132    0.000    0.273    0.000 _reader.py:177(parse_cell)
      126    0.128    0.001    0.128    0.001 {method 'feed' of 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser' objects}
       48    0.099    0.002    0.099    0.002 {method 'GetTypeComp' of 'PyITypeInfo' objects}
   151270    0.098    0.000    0.144    0.000 worksheet.py:793(_move_cell)
        3    0.098    0.033    0.827    0.276 _reader.py:350(bind_cells)
   757136    0.090    0.000    0.090    0.000 worksheet.py:373(<genexpr>)
```

Any thoughts on why it might be taking so long for control to return to the caller?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you create the Excel object via `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch()`? ie changing from late to early binding on the COM interface? Or if you leave out `xl.Quit`?

Comment: @DS_London Wow, `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` cuts the runtime down to about 4 seconds total! Thank you much!!